# How to convert Pandas dictonary data to Jijna HTML of Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have this dictonary value generated from my python code, version 3.

```
@app.route('/rulebook',methods = ['POST','GET'])
def rulebook():
    data = pd.read_excel('rule_book.xlsx')
    pd_data = data.to_dict()
    print(pd_data)
    return render_template('rulebook.html', titlepage = 'RuleBook',pd_data=pd_data)
```

**Output:-**

```
{'RULE_CODE': {0: 'R001', 1: 'R002'}, 'RULE_DESC': {0: 'ACT vs ANT1', 1: 'MEMvs SCREEN'}, 'COMMENTS': {0: 'Validation', 1: 'source Load'}}
```

and I need to use that dictionary into an `jinja` HTML code as like below.

```
<table>
{% for t in pd_data %}
    <tr>
    {% for i in t %}
        <td>{{ i }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Desired output:
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide your desired output example?

Comment: Added desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for simple jinja template you may use it. It will convert `DataFrame` into `html-table`:

Backend:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    aa={'RULE_CODE': {0: 'R001', 1: 'R002'}, 'RULE_DESC': {0: 'ACT vs ANT1', 1: 'MEMvs SCREEN'}, 'COMMENTS': {0: 'Validation', 1: 'source Load'}}
    df=pd.DataFrame(aa)
    print(df.columns.values)
    return render_template('index.html',column_names=df.columns.values,row_data=list(df.values.tolist()), zip=zip)
```

Frontend:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for col in column_names  %}
                <th> {{col}} </th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
    {% for row in row_data %}
        <tr>
            {% for col, row_ in zip(column_names, row) %}
                <td> {{row_}} </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly convert the `DataFrame` into `HTML`. And Use safe filter inside `Jinja` like `{pd_data|safe}`

```
def rulebook():
    data = pd.read_excel('rule_book.xlsx')
    pd_data = data.to_html()
```

Reference [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html)

Comment: As i'm a newbie to python flask, Can you help me with the sample jinja code to get the desired result ?

Comment: @lazarcognos you can visit [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68445152/12446721)